# SELECT from database WHERE some parammeter is equal to a portion of a string var

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im checking the "validity" (if is authorized to make something) of a domain trying to retrieve it from my database, the url came to my script over a GET var and then i just query the database:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];             // complete url of the site like: sub1.domain.com/page/1/some
$url = parse_url($_GET['url']);  // parsing the url http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
$host = $url['host'];            // gives me sub1.domain.com
```

After parsing:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM domains_table WHERE domain = '" . $host . "'";
```

This works great, the think is sometimes domain.com have many sub domains and I cant save in database all the variations. It seems to me a lost of space if lets say domain.com have 30 sub domains and then I need to save sub1.domain.com sub2.domain.com and so...

Instead I was thinking in a more smart way, like saving in data base just ***.domain.com** and then somehow (and this is where i need help) in the query or in the php script (better if is in the query, personal taste) create something that tells * could be any string. How can i do this?

**EDIT:**

There is some confusion in the answers so I try to explain better my self:

If i have in my table saved on the url field: ***.domain1.com** how can i make something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM domain WHERE url LIKE "sub1.domain.com"
```

To retrieve something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use MySQL's **[Like](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)** operator.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value LIKE '%string%';
```

The *%* matches any string before or after the "string" part.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear, im using 'SELECT * FROM domain WHERE url LIKE "' . $url['host'] . '"' where $url['host'] is "sub1.domain.com" and in database i have saved %.domain.com, this query gave me a empty result

Comment: Okay, so make sure you have `*.domain.com` saved in your database. 

Then, let's say you want to check if "sub1.domain.com" is there. You first: `$domain = explode('.', $url['host']);`. This gives you array('sub','domain','com');` 

Then you grab the last two only. `array_shift($domain); $string = implode('.', $domain);`. You now have "domain.com" in $string. 

Now you do your SQL query... WHERE domain LIKE '%" . $string . "'";

Comment: In pseudo code, pop off all strings until you just have "domain.com". Then search for that in the DB with anything allowed before it using MySQL's LIKE.

Comment: the explode is a problem, it will not always work, sometimes i can have hosts like sub1.domain.com and that will work but sometimes i could have somesite.com (no sub domain) or even somesite.com.ve in the last case your script will take somesite as the subdomain

Comment: Okay, will you ever have "sub1.sub2.somesite.com"? Or will it always be one subdomain max? We need to find a constant here.

Comment: Great. So explode the domain string. You'll need a custom list of allowed endings (don't worry there's a limited amount), like .com, .com.ve etc... match these against your array, any remaining unmatched are your subdomains. THEN you remove the subdomain using the method above and query against the database.

Comment: Alternatively, if you passed these through into your $_GET as ?subdomain=sub1&domain=domain.com --> this would save you a ballache!

Answer (score 2):

You can use % as an asterisk (matches anything before or after)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM domains_table WHERE domain LIKE '%" . $host . "%'";
```

Comment: You need `like` instead of `=` for wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
WHERE domain LIKE '%" . $host . "'"
```

Comment: Ok, you need to take all `subdomains` from the main domain and `$host` here should be like this: `domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using the Wildcard Selector:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM domains_table WHERE domain LIKE '%" . $host . "'";
```

With this you match all subdomains. So with

```
$host = '.domain.com';
```

you also retrieve all subdomains.

But be careful, it's pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can use LIKE here, as your wildcard would be in the data stored on the table rather than something you are directly looking for

Rather more work, but possibly better would be to split the domain up into each section, and then have a parent and child relationship between each section.

So it you had shop.fred.com and news.fred.com you would have something like.

```
id  parent  section
1   NULL    com
2   1   fred
3   2   shop
4   2   news
```

Then drill down through that. Either the simple crude way with recursively executing queries, or uses the nested set methods.